# convex and compact set

Tags: convex-analysis

Hello guys I am struggling to solve this exercise could someone help me please! The question is the following:

> Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$ be a convex and compact set. For $i=1,\ldots,n$, let $f_i: S \to S$ be continuous functions. Show that there is an $x \in S$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x) = nx$.

Comment: Here a [Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Define $g(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x)$. Since $S$ is convex, $g$ maps $S$ into $S$. Also clearly $g$ is continuous. So, by [Brouwer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowser_(character)), there is some $x \in S$ with $g(x) = x$. That's what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help!